# add entry to host /etc/hosts file when a docker container is started

Tags: docker

I want to be able to add hostnames to my laptop /etc/hosts that maps to a docker container. Since container ips are not static, each site I start/restart a container I would need to update the /etc/hosts file manually which is not very practical.

I am looking for a simple way to solve this.
I could do some sort of script, which listens to docker events, checks for container ip and updates /etc/hosts but I dont want to reinvent the wheel. (something like this: https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-spotter) but I couldnt really understand how it works.

Anybody has a suggestion?.
Thank you.

Comment: I am using registrator and skydns for this very purpose. I wrote about this for a different question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033884/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-a-unit-started-on-a-machine-and-use-it-in-anothe/29036947#29036947

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using in your *docker-compose.yml* using [`extra_hosts`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra-hosts). For instance:

```
version: '2'
services:
  daemon:
    build: ./
    extra_hosts:
      - "example.com:127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: extra_hosts is *inside* the container.  OP wants to access containers from the host.