# Add Docker Container IP to Host Machine /etc/host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am just learning the ropes with Docker, however one thing seems to of stumped me. I have tried to find answers to my question elsewhere ([add entry to host /etc/hosts file when a docker container is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183833/add-entry-to-host-etc-hosts-file-when-a-docker-container-is-started)) but none really seemed to solve my question.

I am using docker-compose version 2 and `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: php:5-apache
    extra_hosts:
      - "example.com:127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - "80"
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t /var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    restart: always
```

I want to be able to go to `example.com` on the host machine and have it point to the docker container. Also, it seems like docker containers IP's can change on restart? Is  there a way to keep track of the IP even after restart?

I guess what I am after is similar to: https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater

Answer (score 2):

The docker engine doesn't manage the `/etc/hosts` file on the host machine, only inside the containers (but using the DNS service is preferred to that).

You can modify the `/etc/hosts` file by any other method on your host (by hand or using a configuration management tool).

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there's an easy way to somehow set up a "small DNS" and make the thing work the way topic starter describes it.

Answer (score 1):

You should search for Docker hostupdater on Google. There are many docker containers that make it possible, although most of them only work with a Linux host machine.

For example you can try this project :
https://github.com/grachevko/docker-hosts-updater